# Problem in using Elementor tool for default Home page in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, elementor

I'm new to WordPress. I'm learning Elementor. I used elementor on different pages i've made but i don't know how to use it on the which come's as default where the posts are showing.That page is not visible in the pages section of the Wordpress Dashboard. Can someone help me.
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using elementor pro you can modify the default pages like the post and product in the templates -> theme builder, and choose single article for example.
Once modified this will modify all the post design.
This option is only possible on the pro version.